# iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--tcp-flags"

Tags: iptables

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1300                   
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--tcp-flags"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I get this error while adding iptable commands. Any ideas?
my OS:
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
Architecture: x86-64

Comment: what distro is it, ```hostnamectl```, I pasted the exact command on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with iptables v1.8.7 and works normally

Comment: Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS              
          Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
    Architecture: x86-64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem. I needed sudo access.
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1300`

Comment: have not seen a poorer error message for sudo access. Thanks buddy. Saved me!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `--syn`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1300
```

Alternatively, you could try upgrading your version of `iptables` to a newer release that supports the `--tcp-flags` option:

```
iptables --version
```